# Ошибка EAGAIN при запуске docker контейнера

Tags: linux, docker

Пишу веб-приложение с запуском докер-контейнеров. Контейнер запускается из node.js, к нему "прикручен" volume, при старте выполняется команда `python путь/к/файлу.py` (запускает скрипт из контейнера).
Но при этом возникает проблема - при запуске возникает такая ошибка:

```
Error: connect EAGAIN /var/run/docker.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -11,
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/var/run/docker.sock'
}
Error: connect EAGAIN /var/run/docker.sock
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: В целом, это нормально - сокет какбы говорит вам, что он не готов и надо попытать счастья в другой раз.

Comment: @gbg это происходит каждый раз